# Likelihood of probability of heads = 0.5 given that the coin yields 4 heads in 9 tosses.

Tags: conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

Suppose I have a coin.

The probability of heads is unknown.

I toss the coin 9 times and get 4 heads.
What is the likelihood that probability of heads(Ph) is 0.5

**What I have tried till now**

```
Likelihood  of Ph being 0.5 given I have 4 heads from 9 tosses = Probability of getting 4 heads from 9 tosses when Ph is 0.5/Probability of getting 4 heads from 9 tosses when Ph varies from 0 to 1
```

In equation form:

```
P(Ph=0.5|4 heads from 9 tosses) = P(4 heads from 9 tosses|Ph=0.5)/P(getting 4 heads from 9 tosses)
```

Since coin tosses follow binomial distribution

$P(4 heads from 9 tosses|Ph=0.5) = 9C4 (0.5^4) * (1-0.5)^5               \tag{1}$

$P(getting 4 heads from 9 tosses) = 9C4 \int_0^1 (Ph^4)(1-Ph)^5 \, dPh \tag{2}$

where Ph varies from 0 to 1

But dividing eqn (1) and (2) yields a number greater than 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likelihood is only the numerator of your calculation

$L(\frac{1}{2})=\binom{9}{4}(\frac{1}{2})^9\approx 0.246$

what you were triyng to calculate is the posterior density of $\theta$

$$f(\theta|\mathbf{x})=\frac{\binom{9}{4}\theta^4(1-\theta)^5}{\int_0^1 \binom{9}{4}p^4(1-p)^5 dp}=1260\cdot\theta^4(1-\theta)^5$$

Which is a $Beta(5;6)$ distribution

Please, for future posts, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply... Completely forgot that posterior distribution in this case is continious. My bad

Comment: @tommik I am reading out of interest - if no trouble, but what is $\theta$?

Comment: @WA Don: $\theta$ is the unknown parameter; in this case the probability to hit Head in a coin toss. In this logic the parameter has its own density

Comment: @tommik.  Thanks, that is very interesting.  I did not know that one could obtain the probability density for the parameter $\theta$ given the result of a specific sample of tosses and no other information.

Comment: The information are included in the Statistical model that, in this case, is a Binomial model and with the use of Bayes Theorem. Usually you look at the $P(X=x) \sim Bin(n;\theta)$ as a function of  the observation x but in the Bayesian logic, you reverse your point of view....looking at the binomial model as a function of the parameter $\theta$. The result is a Beta distribution

Comment: If we take the prior distribution of $\theta$ as uniform on $[0,1],$ this is correct. If you actually choose a coin out of some change you received while shopping, what makes this a reasonable prior?

Comment: @David K: as you surely know, the prior is chosen by the experimenter in a way to summarize his knowledge of the phenomena. A reasonable prior is again a Beta, a conjugate distribution (reasonably a Beta symmetric around 0.5). In this very preliminary explanation of the logic I didn't introduce the prior (assuming an uniform[ 0;1] prior without telling it )

Comment: @David - that is what I had thought and why I was surprised that there is a distribution for $\theta$ without making additional assumptions.  I had thought one can only make a statement about the magnitude of the probability of a head if you make some assumption about the distribution.  If in fact you knew that 999,999 coins out of a million were fair and one in a million had two heads I think you get a different answer.  So which conclusion is right?

Comment: In fact in real life we do not know the probability of heads for any coin. (There is evidence that the probability of heads depends more on how the coin is tossed than on the coin itself, but to make this question meaningful let's suppose we have controlled for that.) So for something reasonable to call a "coin", for a procedure reasonable to call a "toss", the prior ought to be somewhat tightly concentrated somewhere in the middle of the interval $[0,1].$ But I honestly don't know how to assign a good prior for a given experiment.

Answer (score 2):

To be more specific and replying to @WA Don in few words, let's take the binomial distribution

$\mathbb{P}[X=x|\theta]=\binom{n}{x}\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}$

$x=0,1,2,...,n$

If you look at this function as a function of $\theta$ you can ignore the normalization constant $\binom{n}{x}$ and say that the function is

$\mathbb{P}[\theta|\mathbf{x}]\propto\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}$

Immediately you recognize now the core of a [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) that is

$Beta (\alpha;\beta)\sim \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta}\theta^{\alpha-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta-1}$

$\theta \in [0;1]$